# Does conda work on a production shared-hosted server like dreamhost?

Tags: python, django, anaconda, dreamhost, conda

I just downloaded and tried the continuum analytics' Anaconda3 on a ubuntu linux box. Everything went fine and my Django based website works fine locally using packages installed within a conda created virtual environment. My conjecture is that conda created virtual environment can't be activated the same way as normal python venv:

ubuntu (this works):

```
source <path-to-venv>/bin/activate
```

ubuntu (this does not work):

```
source <path-to-conda-created-virtual-environment>/bin/activate
Error: no environment provided
```

ubuntu (this works):

```
source <conda-created-virtual-environment-name> activate
```

I would now want to make conda setup on a Dreamhost shared-host (meaning get all the matplotlib, numpy, scipy etc. python libraries through conda instead of individually installing via pip). My website is Django based. The issue is that Dreamhost uses Passenger to interface with Apache. Inside the passenger_wsgi.py, I specify the virtual environment to be set. So how do I tell passenger about the conda created virtual environment?

Also, is conda meant to be installed on a production server, meaning is it the norm to manage packages via conda on a Django based shared-host production server? Or the conda package manager is mainly targeted at productivity machines?

Comment: looks like conda is mainly meant for productivity machines or a dedicated server. The non-standard way of launching the conda-created virtual environment makes it incompatible for use with most shared-host servers where you have limited direct access to the Apache/nginx server and usually have to go through middleware like Passenger when interfacing with the server.

Comment: Not sure if this is any help, you can quite easily use conda on Heroku. I know that's a bit different, but works pretty well. You just need a conda buildpack for Heroku.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out @faph . So the issue is with the hosting service provider as there are others who do provide this capability. I will follow it up with Dreamhost to see if there is a way to get conda-created-virtual-environment picked up by passenger_wsgi.py

Comment: I'm struggling with this too. I've tried installing on Bluehost and GreenGeeks, but especially with their new JailShell system, it's throwing permissions errors that I think have to do with symlinks to system packages. I've made forum posts and a conda issue. If I get any answers, I'll post back here.